# Error when communicating with the native messaging host (chrome token signing)

Tags: c++, google-chrome, visual-c++, google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

I installed chrome token signing from github, after building the native messaging and loading the extension in Google chrome it return  a window cmd ,I have an error when I exit or put any string 
Error when communicating with the native messaging host

Comment: Can you show your code and logs of the error?

Comment: @Mr.Rebot log error  Background page activated
TEST: ERROR  {"message":"Error when communicating with the native messaging host."}

Answer (score 0):

**background.js**

```
 * Chrome token signing extension
  *
 * This library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
 * modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
 * License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
 * version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
 *
* This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
* but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
* MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
 * Lesser General Public License for more details.
 *
* You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
* License along with this library; if not, write to the Free Software
* Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA  02110-1301     USA
*/

var NO_NATIVE_URL = "https://open-eid.github.io/chrome-token-signing/missing.html";
var HELLO_URL = "https://open-eid.github.io/chrome-token-signing/hello.html";
var DEVELOPER_URL = "https://github.com/open-eid/chrome-token-signing/wiki/DeveloperTips";

  var NATIVE_HOST = "ee.ria.esteid";
  var K_SRC = "src";
  var K_ORIGIN = "origin";
  var K_NONCE = "nonce";
  var K_RESULT = "result";
  var K_TAB = "tab";
  var K_EXTENSION = "extension";
  // Stores the longrunning ports per tab
  // Used to route all request from a tab to the same host instance
 var ports = {};
  // Probed to false if host component is OK.
  var missing = true;
  console.log("Background page activated");
  // XXX: probe test, because connectNative() does not allow to check the   presence
   // of native component for some reason
  typeof chrome.runtime.onStartup !== 'undefined' &&     chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(function() {
  // Also probed for in onInstalled()
  _testNativeComponent().then(function(result) {
    if (result === "ok") {
        missing = false;
    } });
        });

  // Force kill of native process
  // Becasue Port.disconnect() does not work
  function _killPort(tab) {
if (tab in ports) {
    console.log("KILL " + tab);
    // Force killing with an empty message
    ports[tab].postMessage({});
}
 }

  // Check if native implementation is OK resolves with "ok", "missing"   or "forbidden"
  function _testNativeComponent() {
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    chrome.runtime.sendNativeMessage(NATIVE_HOST, {text: "some_valid_argument"}, function(response) {
   if (!response) {
            console.log("TEST: ERROR  " + JSON.stringify(chrome.runtime.lastError));
            // Try to be smart and do some string matching
            var permissions = "Access to the specified native messaging host is forbidden.";
            var missing = "Specified native messaging host not found.";
            if (chrome.runtime.lastError.message === permissions) {
                resolve("forbidden")
            } else if (chrome.runtime.lastError.message === missing) {
                resolve("missing");
            } else {
                resolve("missing");
            }
        } else {
            console.log("TEST: " + JSON.stringify(response));
            if (response["result"] === "invalid_argument") {
                resolve("ok");
            } else {
                resolve("missing"); // TODO: something better here
            }
        }
    });
});
  }


 // When extension is installed, check for native component or direct to helping page
 typeof chrome.runtime.onInstalled !== 'undefined' && chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function(details) {
if (details.reason === "install" || details.reason === "update") {
    _testNativeComponent().then(function(result) {
            var url = null;
            if (result === "ok" && details.reason === "install") {
                // Also set the flag, onStartup() shall be called only
                // on next startup
                missing = false;
                // TODO: Add back HELLO page on install
                // once there is a nice tutorial
                 url = HELLO_URL;
                 console.log('succes'+ url);
            } else if (result === "forbidden") {
                url = DEVELOPER_URL;
            } else if (result === "missing"){
                url = NO_NATIVE_URL;
            }
            if (url) {
                chrome.tabs.create({'url': url + "?" + details.reason});
            }
    });
}
   });

  // When message is received from page send it to native
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
if(sender.id !== chrome.runtime.id && sender.extensionId !== chrome.runtime.id) {
    console.log('WARNING: Ignoring message not from our extension');
    // Not our extension, do nothing
    return;
}
if (sender.tab) {
    // Check if page is DONE and close the native component without doing anything else
    if (request["type"] === "DONE") {
        console.log("DONE " + sender.tab.id);
        if (sender.tab.id in ports) {
            // FIXME: would want to use Port.disconnect() here
            _killPort(sender.tab.id);
        } 
    } else {
        request[K_TAB] = sender.tab.id;
        if (missing) {
            _testNativeComponent().then(function(result) {
                if (result === "ok") {
                    missing = false;
                    _forward(request);
                } else {
                    return _fail_with(request, "no_implementation");
                }
            });
        } else {
            // TODO: Check if the URL is in allowed list or not
            // Either way forward to native currently
            _forward(request);
        }
    }
}
    });

   // Send the message back to the originating tab
  function _reply(tab, msg) {
msg[K_SRC] = "background.js";
msg[K_EXTENSION] = chrome.runtime.getManifest().version;
chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab, msg);
  }
  // Fail an incoming message if the underlying implementation is not
  // present
  function _fail_with(msg, result) {
var resp = {};
resp[K_NONCE] = msg[K_NONCE];
resp[K_RESULT] = result;
_reply(msg[K_TAB], resp);
  }
 // Forward a message to the native component
 function _forward(message) {
var tabid = message[K_TAB];
console.log("SEND " + tabid + ": " + JSON.stringify(message));
// Open a port if necessary
if(!ports[tabid]) {
    // For some reason there does not seem to be a way to detect missing components from longrunning ports
    // So we probe before opening a new port.
    console.log("OPEN " + tabid + ": " + NATIVE_HOST);
    // create a new port
    var port = chrome.runtime.connectNative(NATIVE_HOST);
    // XXX: does not indicate anything for some reason.
    if (!port) {
        console.log("OPEN ERROR: " + JSON.stringify(chrome.runtime.lastError));
    }
    port.onMessage.addListener(function(response) {
        if (response) {
            console.log("RECV "+tabid+": " + JSON.stringify(response));
            _reply(tabid, response);
        } else {
            console.log("ERROR "+tabid+": " + JSON.stringify(chrome.runtime.lastError));
            _fail_with(message, "technical_error");
        }
    });
    port.onDisconnect.addListener(function() {
        console.log("QUIT " + tabid);
        delete ports[tabid];
        // TODO: reject all pending promises for tab, if any
    });
    ports[tabid] = port;
    ports[tabid].postMessage(message);
} else {
    // Port already open
    ports[tabid].postMessage(message);
}
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(
   function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
if (sender.url == blacklistedWebsite)
  return;  // don't allow this web page access
if (request.openUrlInEditor)
  openUrl(request.openUrlInEditor);
   });
```

**the error**
Background page activated
                                                          TEST: ERROR  {"message":"Error when communicating with the native messaging host."}

when I run the extension I have:
[image]

And when I whrite somethig or click 2 times at Enter touch or close the cmd I have this:[image]